# How do I add the same element to an array multiple times?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making shopping cart,and I am a little bit confused. There is a counter which counts number of current product. For example: the user can buy 5 book or more. So , I need to make a function which adds the element аs many times as the user will select it.

I made something like this:

```
[...state.shoppingCart, new Array(state.booksNumber).fill({...action.book})]
```

But of course it makes a new array in array... So how can I just add elements to an array without deleting old elements or creating a new array inside the array?

**I need a functional way, no loops.**

Comment: Like using myArray.push(something)? You don't really provide enough code here to make a clear answer...How exactly does the code you pasted get called??

Comment: @Zachucks I guess in this way it ads only 1 element, but i need for example to add 5 times this element for 1 click...

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: _"I need to make a function which adds the element аs many times as the user will select it"_ - Why? Just store what product and how many of them (number)

Comment: Just add the spread operator before `new Array`, so `[...state.shoppingCart, ...new Array(state.booksNumber).fill({...action.book})]`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey exactly!!! add the answer!

Comment: Or `state.shoppingCart.concat(Array(state.boosNumber).fill(action.book))` - you don't need `new` or `{...action.book}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the spread syntax again:

```
[...state.shoppingCart, ...new Array(state.booksNumber).fill({...action.book})]
```

That will spread the new array into the existing array.

Comment: `new` can be dropped, `.fill({...action.book})` can be `.fill(action.book)`

Comment: @Thankyou lots of things can be changed. If you'd like to add another answer, feel free to. This answer is the minimal change needed to provide the outcome requested.

Comment: And that comment was the minimal change needed to make the code not bad lol :D

Answer (score 1):

```
const newArray = new Array(state.booksNumber).fill({...action.book})
[...state.shoppingCart, ...newArray]
```

Comment: adding a verbal explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat method

```
 const a = new Array([1,3,4]).concat([1,3,4])
 console.log(a)
```

This will add the elements into the array.

Or you can try with spread operator.

```
const arr=[1,2,3,4]
const a = new Array([1,3,4,.... arr]);
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the spread operator inside the returning array for the new Array you created.

Adding the spread operator allows you to merge/concat both array items.

For example:

```
const arrayOne = [1,2,3];
const arrayTwo = [4,5,6];
const mergedArrays = [...arrayOne, ...arrayTwo] //[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Also assuming `action.book` is an object you want to add multiple times inside of the `new Array()` you've created, there is no need to spread it as it will fill the array with each object.

This function might help out with what you are looking for:

```
const addMultipleItems = (action) => {
    const items = new Array(state.booksNumber).fill(action.book);
    return [...state.shoppingCart, ...items];
}
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation to your answer.